# Identify a div by the properties of two child divs

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to identify the row div that matches two criteria (category and location). This will allow me to do an storeXpathCount on those rows that match the xpath - so I can confirm the correct number of rows are displayed.

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="cs_course_list_row cs_default">
   <div class="cs_course_category">Cat 1150 31397 A</div>
   <div class="cs_course_location">Loc 1150 31397 A </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to identify the div with the class 'cs_course_list_row' based on the content in the inner divs. This is what I have tried (among many other permutations):

```
//div[contains(@class,'cs_course_list_row') and contains[div(contains(.,'Loc 1150 31397 A'))] and contains[div(contains(.,'Cat 1150 31397 A'))]]
```

Notice the space after 'Loc 1150 31397 A' in the second div, hence the use of 'contains' and not =

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `XPath` to match required `div`

```
//div[contains(@class,'cs_course_list_row') and ./div[normalize-space()='Loc 1150 31397 A'] and ./div[normalize-space()='Cat 1150 31397 A']]
```